# Entity Framework parallel task vs WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, task-parallel-library

I need to insert some data and I'm doing it by calling WCF from my UI and passing a list of objects. Then the service calls a lower business layer which inserts sequentialy the items (calling several other managers and making a lots of call/insert throught ObjectContext)

Now the problem I can't understand is this:

- If I call the service more times and passing items one by one everything works fine, inserts goes in parallel and I get some performance benefit concerning time.
- If I try to call a parallel foreach in the service class I got an exeception, because ObjectContext is it not thread-safe, but I can't lock code every time I use it because it happens too many time

Why if I call WCF does it work? Is there a way to do the same in my manager class?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your service configuration a new instance is created for every parallel service-call. But using a parallel loop within the service will cause the same ObjectContext to be used multiple times. So basically, calling parallel via WCF creates multiple ObjectContexts where executing within the WCF service only uses one (which as you know, is not thread-safe). Depending on the nature of your inserts this might be okay. You could also spin up multiple ObjectContexts within the service.

Some of this is wild guessing, because you can actually influence the behavior of the WCF service to not run multiple instances, but judging from the behavior your experience, this should be the reason, why you can perform parallel inserts using the WCF service and not within the WCF service.

Comment: That's more or less what I was thinking, but in that case if I start every loop with a new ObjectContext before doing anything that would be like calling WCF, is it right? Instead it doesn't work too

Comment: When it comes to parallel processing, there are a number of pitfalls, can you somehow determine how many parallel tasks are actually executed when using the WCF service vs. inside the WCF service? Consider the following, Paralle.For rougly scales to the number of processors available, where a WCF service might be limited to an arbitrary number. Also, what kind of exception did you get, when instantiating the ObjectContext within the parallel loop?

Comment: I get exception several different errors, like "invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed" or "Entity xxx mapped more than once". They seems error that shouldn't be exist with different context

Comment: Indeed, but without code, I cannot determine whether you have some kind of inter-thread communication (what kind of EF entities do you use: Self-tracking, POCO or the default EntityObject?)

Comment: Done! It was just an operation who access and recalculates the same records from every inserting, I've locked that part of code and now everything works fine! I've just another question, do you think this is the best method to perform parallel inserting in db through EF?

Comment: Since MSDN explicitly states that ObjectContext isn't thread-safe, I would assume, that it is the only method for doing so. Another way would be to disable change-tracking and so on, to get really light-weight entities, but without further digging into the internals of EF I can't tell whether it is possible.